# List Items appear correctly in one row but not in some others

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am having a really weird and strange problem and I am not sure what is causing it. You can only understand it once you have seen it.  Here is the link:

http://daccordinc.com/daccor/?wpsc_product_category=guayabera&paged=3

(Select grid view by clicking on small icon under heading) As you can see the first row in grid correctly displays 5 items in the list. But second grid only displays 5th element and other 4 elements are in third row. So basically the grid breaks down on some pages.

What makes this problem stranger is that products and css classes are pulled from a database table using and are same for all products. So if the first row displays correctly others should also as they have same css. To make the matters worse this problem appears only in some pages of grid view and others display fine. It is a wordpress site.

Sorry I don't even know what is causing that problem and I have tried inspect element etc. So I can't post any code. Please take a look at the link.

Regards
Ahmar.

Comment: it's not weird, the content of your list items is different so some are *higher* than others. `float:left` will attempt to fill up to the top and *not* start at the left if not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of the float property and the fact that some of your elements have different height. Since your elements have a set width and are already using `display:inline-block;` you just need to remove the float and align them all vertically.

Try adding this to your CSS

```
.wpsc_default_product_list.grid .default_product_display {
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: THanks man it works. Can you please tell the reason also why float:left; was not working?

Comment: @AhmarAli, read the comments section as Bazzz has already explained the issue